# How much electricity can be directly generated from air humidity?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, estimation, nanoscience, humidity

There have been some recent papers on harvesting electrical energy from air humidity using nanoengineered materials:

- "[Power generation from ambient humidity using protein nanowires](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-020-2010-9)" in *Nature*
- "[Generic Air-Gen Effect in Nanoporous Materials for Sustainable Energy Harvesting from Air Humidity](https://doi.org/10.1002/adma.202300748)" in *Advanced Materiels*

These articles are paywalled, but have some popular science articles, e.g.

- "[There’s Something in the Air: Deploying protein nanowires to generate electricity from ambient humidity](https://www.yalescientific.org/2020/05/theres-something-in-the-air-deploying-protein-nanowires-to-generate-electricity-from-ambient-humidity/)"
- "[This New Device Generates Electricity From Thin Air](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/this-new-device-generates-electricity-from-thin-air-180982263/)"
- "[Nanopores are the secret to making electricity from thin air](https://www.nanowerk.com/nanotechnology-news2/newsid=63048.php)"
- "[Scientists Working to Generate Electricity From Thin Air Make Breakthrough](https://www.vice.com/en/article/93kade/scientists-working-to-generate-electricity-from-thin-air-make-breakthrough)

and at least [one patent application](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2020069523).

**Can the theoretical maximum energy harvesting rate be estimated per unit area of the material, and if yes, what is it?**  I guess this should be calculable from the air humidity, temperature, and pressure, and the latent heat of condensation of water, possibly with some assumptions about air flow over the surfaces.  (I assume the energy is coming from condensation which means the device also produces possibly useful liquid water, but I don't immediately see this mentioned in the articles.)

The [EU has provided €3M](https://cordis.europa.eu/project/id/101046307) in funding to the [CATCHER project](https://catcherproject.eu/) for developing humidity-to-electricity conversion with an objective of a power density of ~36 mW/g or 15 - 20 mW/cm$^2$, but I don't know if these are theoretical limits or just practical goals.

**Clarification Update**

Just to be clear, I am asking if there is some bound on the energy harvesting rate similar to how the [solar constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant) sets an upper bound on solar energy, how [Carnot's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_(thermodynamics)) limits thermal generation (e.g. as discussed in this [question about thermoelectric generation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/673204/145491)), or how wind turbine power is constrained by the [Betz Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betz%27s_law).  This question is not about how practical the technology is or whether it could compete against wind, hydro, or other power technologies that directly or indirectly also harvest energy from the atmosphere.

Comment: Wasn't taking electricity from humidity the mechanism for John Galt's motor in *Atlas Shrugged*, or am I mistaken on that?

Comment: @Kyle-Kanos It has been decades since I read *Atlas Shrugged*, but according to my quick online search his engine was powered by "atmospheric electricity". I would have guessed that referred to the [vertical atmospheric voltage gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_electricity) and was probably inspired by Nikola Tesla's ideas.

Comment: Oh right, it was [*static* electricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Galt#Character_biography) in the atmosphere. I was close!

Comment: They didn't say how much current per area of material, just a voltage, so we can't estimate what sort of size of device could produce what sort of power. We will have to do experiments and build our own devices to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, @wordsforthewise.  The CATCHER project expects an "output power density of ~36 mW/g or [15 - 20 mW/cm2], which will be ready for scaling up". (Click on "Show the project objective" on their [CORDIS project page](https://cordis.europa.eu/project/id/101046307).) This is comparable to solar power, but presumably would work at night as long as the humidity is present.  This caught my somewhat skeptical eye, but I couldn't figure out if it was realistic, hence my question.

Comment: Aha, amazing @DavidBailey. Sorry, I guess I didn't read the end of your post. From that we should be able to estimate a power density for bigger devices but will have to make lots of assumptions on how the device is designed and would work. I'd be interested in starting a similar project to CATCHER in the US, is there another community you know of where others are working on this?

Comment: @wordsforthewise The [Yao Lab](https://www.junyaoumass.org/) whose research triggered the recent media interest would likely know of any US efforts.  This [article](https://cleantechnica.com/2023/07/03/making-electricity-from-the-humidity-in-the-air-started-with-an-accident/) mentions one [startup](https://cascatachuva.eu/) in Europe that produces 10 mW at 1.5 V from a 4 cm diameter disk, i.e. 1 mW/cm^2.

Comment: I am not into meteorology, so someone correct me... but isn't a hurricane mostly driven by moist, warm air masses? There have to be many GW of power in such a storm and it can rage for days. So the answer is that on a technically relevant scale we are talking about wind power here.

Comment: @FlatterMann I agree that wind power might be stretched to be relevant the question title, but that is not the specific direct humidity-to-electricity technology I am asking about in the question. I have added "directly" to the title to reduce any possible confusion. People seem to be putting money and time into the developing this technology, but I couldn't find any estimates of whether it is actually likely to be useful or economically relevant.

Comment: People have been putting a lot more time and money in wind power for all I can tell and it is both useful and economically relevant. No offense intended. Would you like to move this to chat?

Comment: @FlatterMann I've added an update to the question that I hope clarifies what I am asking. I am not disputing that wind power is likely much more useful and a better place to invest time and money.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the latent energy required to condense 1 mol of water from vapor to gas, find the mols of water in a $\rm cm^3$ of air as a function of temperature and relative humidity, and then get the maximum energy per $\rm cm^3$ of air a X temperature and Y humidity.  If you are simply looking for this maximum possible harvesting value, it should be relatively simple.

Comment: Thanks @RC_23. Yes, it is relatively easy to calculate the latent energy per unit volume in a humid volume of air, but it is not so easy to estimate the rate at which that energy could be harvested.  All the proposals seem to be membranes with a humidity generated potential, so my question is about the maximum energy harvesting rate per unit area of the membrane, which is a metric used by the researchers.  They talk about having stacks of membranes to increase the total power.

Comment: My gut feeling says that the energy harvested would be vastly less than the energy required to move or push the air to be harvested.  And if the energy to evaporate the water vapor into the air in the first place ultimately comes from solar heating, it seems much more efficient to simply harvest that directly with a solar panel.